# Pinnacle cart configuration - while moving to live server

Tags: php, configuration, shopping-cart, cart, pinnacle-cart

What are the Basic configuration changes (while making the site live) for a site build-ed using pinnacle cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upload all the files to live server.
2. Change the urls

   1. Change the path in `htaccess`
   2. Change the `globalHttpsUrl`, `globalHttpUrl` and `global server path` in `setttings` table of database.
3. Give write permission to all the files mentioned by pinnacle cart (.htaccess, images, templates, _custom, etc..)
4. Change the database details given in engine_config.php file
5. Change `define('devmode', true);` to `define('devmode', false);`